# How to show Arabic Characters in Google Charts Labels

Tags: charts

This is the code that i am using, and the arabic characters show as question marks. I tried searching on the internet, but i didnt find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Graph</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-height,minimum-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=3.0,user-scalable=yes" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    //google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'], language: 'ar' });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['التواريخ',
 'التواريخ', 'المبلغ'],
['2004', 1000, 400], ['2005', 1170, 460], ['2006', 660, 1120], ['2007', 1030, 540]]);
        var options = { title: 'الاستهلاك الشهري', hAxis: 
{ title: 'التواريخ',   titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' } } };
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='chart_div' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

should be

```
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-16' />
```